# How can I try a new language or framework without installing it?

Tags: web-applications, sandbox

With so many languages and frameworks that exist, and with new ones appearing all the time, I don't have the time to download, install, and configure each one to evaluate it. In the past I've run across webapps that allow one to write or paste code into a window, and see the results in realtime in the browser, usually in a tutorial setting.

What are your favorite sandbox sites for a given technology?

**Edit:** @fretj provided the link to the excellent [Google Code Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/) (+1 upvote), but I thought that it was just for experimenting with Google's own apps (Search, Maps, Earth, Language, etc). But it turns out that it contains a few hidden gems: In addition to their apps, you can try out the many Javascript libraries that they host including [jQuery](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#jquery), [jQuery UI](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#jqueryui), [MooTools](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#mootools), [Dojo](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#dojo), and [Prototype Scriptaculous](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#prototype_scriptaculous).

They're all hidden under the Libraries category in the "Pick an API" box. I overlooked the category because I thought it was for an app called Google Libraries. There's also a Javascript category for Javascript itself.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/) includes mini-sandboxes in many lessons of their tutorials. Each example is used to illustrate that particular lesson, but you can add to or change the code to use it as a sandbox. There are examples for Javascript, DOM scripting, Ajax, SQL, ADO, ASP and ASP.NET.

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com) is a sandbox for Javascript and CSS testing, with built in support for many scripting libraries, including jQuery, script.aculo.us, YUI, MooTools and  dojo. So you can try out example code without downloading and installing each of the libraries. In addition it allows you to save your code snippets with a unique URL (like a pastebin), and allows collaborative editing of each snippet.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/) is a collaborative sandbox for front-end developers that is focused on HTML, CSS, and JS. You can customize many aspects of the interface, including the JS libraries that you want to include, several CSS features (like adding a reset.css), and other bonuses like Emmet and Vim key bindings.

<strike>[Try Ruby](http://tryruby.hobix.com/) is an very basic interactive tutorial that introduces Ruby to the complete novice.  It's done in a serial fashion, so you have to go from start to finish in one go, but it doesn't take long.</strike> [Try Ruby was taken down on Aug 19 by its owner [_why](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Why_the_lucky_stiff). Many people hope that his content will return. Why's (poignant) Guide to Ruby has [HTML](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/) and [PDF](http://www.ember.co.nz/resources/whys-poignant-guide-to-ruby/) mirrors.]

[OpenSourceCMS](http://www.opensourcecms.com/) houses dozens of open source software packages and allows you to try out both the front end and the administrative backend functions of the most popular portals, blogs, image galleries, and forums. You have full admin rights and can change any of the content on each of the packages, and then see the results of those changes from the user's perspective.

[JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) is an online JSON validator with syntax checking that isn't overly complicated, but works as advertised.

For regular expressions try [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/) built with Ruby, [RegExPal](http://regexpal.com/) built in Javascript, or [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), which is very helpful for regex beginners because it has code sense built in.

[Codepad](http://codepad.org/) is a pastebin with a twist: it has a interpreter/compiler built in for 13 languages, including C, C++, Haskell, Scheme, Python, and PHP. So you can not only use it to share code, but also to run or test code when you're away from your programming environment (think boring but mandatory meeting or long commute on mass transit, etc.)

Comment: FYI, the Ruby sandbox is currently broken. Everything returns a 502 Bad Gateway response.

Comment: Try Ruby is maintained in spirit at http://tryruby.org/

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is similar to JS Bin, but it has four panes (HTML, CSS, Javascript, and rendered result) that are all open at once. So it feels more efficient than switching between the code and the results in JS Bin. Try some of the examples to start with a not-as-blank canvas.

Comment: @flamingLogos jsFiddle seems to be the defacto standard for adding examples of source code now. I was instructed to do so when I submitted a question regarding it...

Comment: @flamingLogos I prefer [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/). It's [open source](https://github.com/remy/jsbin). It has a live preview panel, with [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) suggestions as you type. Plus, it has a [super customizable editor](http://jsbin.tumblr.com/#post-30025396843) with [Emmet](http://docs.emmet.io/) baked in.

Comment: Use the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) editor (Pastebin-like) for trying out Angular.js

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it totally fits this question, but this is a nice playground I've found recently:

[Google AJAX APIs Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/)

Answer (score 1):

Lua has a [Live demo](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo) on its site. Also show sandbox techniques...

Answer (score 0):

eXist-db has a [sandbox](http://demo.exist-db.org/sandbox/sandbox.xql) that is very helpful for playing with XQuery/XPath.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [Heroku](http://heroku.com/features) for Ruby on Rails, and [AppJet](http://appjet.com) for server-side JavaScript.

Slightly off-topic, but I highly recommend the "Why's Poignant Guide to Ruby" from the same guy who developed the "Try Ruby" site - you won't believe how fast and easy it's to learn Ruby, aided by cartoons!

Comment: Why's Poignant Guide to Ruby is certainly not your average software tutorial! Both left and right brained at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wonderfl](http://wonderfl.net/) to compile and sandbox Flash/Actionscript/etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I have found [repl.it](http://repl.it/) to be extremely useful. Many different languages. One complaint I have is including/importing certain libraries doesn't work very well. For example, you could not run this in repl.it (python)

```
from time import sleep
print "We are going to sleep for 5 seconds."
sleep(5)
print "Now we will sleep for 3 seconds."
sleep(3)
```