# Is there a good browser based sandbox to practice regex?

Tags: regex, sandbox

I am looking for recommendations for a browser based regex sandbox to practice some proof of concept expressions.

Answer (score 14):

I've used http://www.rubular.com/ a few times, seems to do the job.

Answer (score 7):

I like [RegExPal.com](http://regexpal.com). Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

This one's pretty good too: [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Comment: Also has a downloadable AIR app which is nice

Answer (score 1):

Which flavor?  Regex support is included in most of the major programming languages in use today, in editors and IDE's, in command-line tools like grep and findstr, and lots of other places.  Every one of these tools/languages/applications has its own regex flavor, and no two flavors are completely alike.

For the regex flavor of a specific programming language, I just Google for "<language> regex tester"; there always seems to be at least one online tester available.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own Regular Expression (REGEX) Online Test Sandbox with a Match and Replace feature since I could not find one with a Replace feature. It's running under a DOT NET (.NET) Engine. Great for testing Regex patterns, but also good for quick and dirty reformatting of text files and strings.

http://regex.cyberpine.com

Answer (score 0):

Try [NRegEx](http://www.nregex.com/nregex/default.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

http://demo.1060research.com/ep+name@app_regular_expression_cookbook

Answer (score 0):

For online sandboxes for several different languages, platforms, and open source applications, see this similar SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204831/how-can-i-try-a-new-language-or-framework-without-installing-it).

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly handy for .net based stuff:

http://regexlib.com/

Answer (score -3):

I'm biased of course because I wrote it.  But there's a good one for .NET regular expressions called [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/).