# Regex for validation e-mail addresses

Tags: regex, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

I am using the following regular expression to validate e-mail addresses:

```
^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$
```

It doesn't consider the following e-mail address valid: username@q.com, but according to our customer it is a valid e-mail.

How do I modify the following regular expression statement to accept username@q.com as a valid e-mail address?

Comment: The regex pattern you posted was specifically designed to catch common errors at the cost for disallowing some valid email addresses. It surely allows some invalid email addresses at too.

Comment: Comments about using regex to solve this notwithstanding, this specific section @[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\. is what is not matching in this case because it is looking for at least 2 characters between "@" and "." There is a good short reference at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) and a number of sandbox tools listed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463796/is-there-a-good-browser-based-sandbox-to-practice-regex

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a regular expression to check the validity of an e-mailadres? If I would fill in fake@fake.com the regular expression would also say it is valid.

In my opinion, regular expressions take a lot of runtime to evaluate, and mostly do not make you accomplish your goal. Think about why you actually need it, and perhaps go for a simpler one that just checks if it is of the form #@#.# (#=some text)
See: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585